# tcl regexp related to mix of character and number

Tags: regex, tcl, regexp-replace

My file contains

```
roll_number : someNumber ; name(mixOfcharactersAndNumbers) filePathInLinux
```

such as

```
roll_number : 81 ; name(JOHN_23_CARTER) /home/directory/johnc
roll_number : 22 ; name(michael21_Lee) /home/directory/mhlee
```

My regexp was

```
regexp {.*name([a-zA-Z0-9]+.*} $line match name 
regexp {.*name(.*).*} $line match name
```

It seems like due to mix of both number and character I am not able regexp correctly, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issues are that you did not escape `(` char and did not account for the `_` char in your first regex. Also, you do not need to match the whole input, it is not necessary with TCL regex that allows *partial matches*, i.e. matching shorter substrings inside longer ones.

Just match `name(` (with `name\(`) and then capture into Group 1 one or more word chars (with `(\w+)`):

```
set a "roll_number : 81 ; name(JOHN_23_CARTER) /home/directory/johnc"
regexp {name\((\w+)} $a - name
```

See [this TCL demo](http://ideone.com/pkHNi6) printing `JOHN_23_CARTER`.

Also, see an [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQHNTB/1).